# Issue with popping to a previous view (navigation controller)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**The Issue**

So, I found (you are familiar with this if you saw my previous question) that i needed to implement a navigation controller stack. So, i replaced a few of my segues to push segues, in order to push these views onto my navigation stack. Unfortunately, in the third view seen in the picture below, i am trying to use the popping feature to return to the previous view. So far, i have used the recommended code to accomplish such, and to no avail. I hope you guys can spot something i can't!

[image]

**The Code**

Below is the action function for a back button on the third view (unfortunately something is messed up in the screen shot, but rest assured there is a white arrow back button).

```
@IBAction func back(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your NavigationController is not your Initial View Controller.  The  arrow is pointing at the one in the middle, not the one on the left as I would expect.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so so much! I am glad it was something simple haha. If i could accept your answer, i would.  @DavidShaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it looks like your NavigationController is not your Initial View Controller. The arrow is pointing at the one in the middle, not the one on the left as I would expect.

As to your follow up question, removing the navigation bar at the top is easy enough.

Just add this to your UIViewControllers:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
}
```

As far as I know you have to remove it for each UIViewController in your stack.

One other thing.  Your code for "back" can be simplified:

```
@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

In Swift 3:

```
@IBAction func gobackTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

The syntax is dumb, but this is how it is right now.  I would assume at some point `popViewController` will be marked as a `@discardableResult`

Comment: Thank you! And in swift 3, they make you do it the way I had it written.

Comment: Updated it with a Swift 3 syntax example.

Comment: Thank you! You've been a great help